# Retrieve hyperlinked data in excel in VB

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssms, oledb

So I'm trying to create a SSMS database which is no problem and have files stored in the database table which is no problem. My problem is I'm extracting data from excel files (quite a number). They are only small and I have no problem extracting the columns and transferring into the database.

The problem I want to try get around is, within the excel files there is hyperlinks to other files in one the columns (.pdfs, word docs etc.) and I want to be able to read the excel, fill the sql database with the data from excel but also somehow get the hyperlink in some the words and use it to go to the associated file and upload/save it along with the data to the database table.

I know in VBA there is a form of

```
.FollowHyperlink Address
```

which would be handy in vb to get the filepath of the hyperlink but as far as my knowledge of VB goes you can't realy do anything with excel hyperlink data? I look forward to be proven otherwise.

Any other info please ask, Thanks!
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\")`

Or something like this

```
Private Sub Follow_Hyperlink(Link_Address as string)
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Link_Address)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender as object, e as eventargs) handles Button1.Click
    Follow_Hyperlink(me.textbox1.text)
End Sub
```

This is just to get you started there is a lot more you can do with this, [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) where you can get some more info and [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/process-vbnet) is another good example page.